# geopandas color closest shapes the same color

Tags: python, geospatial, polygon, geopandas

I have a geopandas file with 100+ polygons and a sparse set (~10 of which) have a value of interest. Is there an easy way for me to assign the remaining 90+ polygons a value based on the value of the nearest non-zero polygon?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide sample data and perhaps [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: By *spare*, do you mean *sparse*?

Comment: yes, edited. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code below indicates an algorithm that will join the polygons with 'no value' to the closest polygons with a valid value, using a spatial join (nearest neighbor) based on their centroids.

Note the code is a draft of the code you need; it indicates the general algorithm but you need to complete the functions based on your data and your variables.

```
# gdf with all the polygons
gdf1 = gpd.read_file(...)

# calculate a column with the centroid geometry; 
# it will be used later.
# note: this is not the active gdf geometry at this stage
gdf1['geometry_pt'] = gdf1['geometry'].centroid

# set the point geometry as the active geometry
gdf1.set_geometry('geometry_pt')

# filter out the gdf in two gdfs, with/without the value you want
gdf1_yesval = gdf1.loc[gdf1['field1'] != 0]
gdf1_noval  = gdf1.loc[gdf1['field1'] == 0]

# perform a spatial join to assign the closest value to the points with no value
# for this, apply the code in the link below
gdf1_noval_joined = gdf1_noval.apply(...  nearest... gdf1_yesval... )

# do the necessary column operations in the joined gdf 
# to update your desired columns with values from the spatially joined gdf
gdf1_noval_joined['field1'] = gdf1_noval_joined['joinedfieldA']

# delete the unnecessary columns in the joined gdf
gdf1_noval_joined.drop(columns=['joinedfieldA', 'joinedfieldB'], inplace=True)

# concatenate the two gdfs to make one
df2 = pd.concat([gdf1_yesval, gdf1_noval_joined])

# convert it into a gdf again
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry='geometry')
```

The link where the nearest neighbor join function is explained is: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/222315/93912

Hope it helps.